# How do I send a mail which has an attachment of Excel file created by Codeigniter excel library

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a function in my controller which creates excel file using the excel library, however I have to send the excel file created by that function as an attachment to mail. I have no idea how this can be done. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of Codeigniter's email library to send the emails with relevant attachments.
Below is the code snippet, which helps you to achieve the same

```
$this->load->library('email');

$this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
$this->email->to('someone@example.com'); 
$this->email->cc('another@another-example.com'); 
$this->email->bcc('them@their-example.com'); 

$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');  

$this->email->attach('/path/to/excel.xslx');

$this->email->send();
```

For any additional reference you can navigate to [CI Email Doc](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html)
Hope this helps you...

Comment: Thanks for your answer Amit, however I dont have a direct path for my excel file, the file is generated dynamically in a function using Excel library..

Comment: Right.. I understand... You need to move the generated file to some temp folder.. Then send it as an attachment.. and unlink it later....